# Why can't I see close votes even though I have permissions?

Tags: discussion, support, status-bydesign

I can't see close votes, but I have the reputation to see them.  Does the close link only show if at least one person has already voted to close?

I'm getting confused and thinking that when I don't see any close votes that no one has yet voted to close a question.

**What should the screen look like when at least one person has voted to close,** ***and***  **I have permissions to view close votes but not to actually vote to close myself?**

In other words, 3000 rep is required to close.  Obviously.  But 250 reputation is required to **view close votes.**

So, where does one view the close votes when they don't have the ability to close themselves.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You have the ability to cast close and reopen votes on *your own questions* at 250 rep per the faq

https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation

Thus, you will see `close (2)` if there are 2 pending close votes.

Comment: Oh, I misunderstood how **view close votes** worked.  Thanks for clearing that up.